# cakePHP 2.7 add model to app_controller

Tags: model, cakephp-2.7

I have a "categories" table (`Category` model), which i want to use app-wide, in an element.

My thoughts are to add it to the appcontroller, using `$uses = array('Category');`.

however, would it cause any problems while i use the actual `categories` controller?

is there another way to do it?

thanks

Comment: I would create a component

Comment: anyone?          please?